# ERR ERESOLVE while installing react-native-firebase/auth

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

In my react native project, I want to install React Native Firebase Auth but I got error after running this command:

> ```
> npm i @react-native-firebase/auth
> ```

The error :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: KengTung@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @react-native-firebase/app@16.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-firebase/app@"16.5.1" from @react-native-firebase/database@16.5.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/database
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/database@"^16.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-firebase/app@"16.5.1" from @react-native-firebase/storage@16.5.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/storage
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/storage@"^16.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @react-native-firebase/auth@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @react-native-firebase/app@16.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-firebase/app@"16.7.0" from @react-native-firebase/auth@16.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/auth@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

Comment: > My Package.json file:

      ```
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.1",
        "@react-native-firebase/database": "^16.5.1",
        "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^16.5.1",
        "react": "18.1.0",
        "react-native": "0.70.6",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
      
      },
    ```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm i
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain what that code does? OP and new people can have a problem understanding it [Good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)